# How to override the default confirm in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm trying to implement this plugin for a custom confirmation box, but i'm a little lost as far as the return values go. Here's the original:

```
jQuery("a.confirm").click( function() { 

if ( confirm( '<?php _e( 'Are you sure?' ) ?>' ) ) return true; else return false;

});
```

and this what I'm trying to implement:

```
$("a.confirm").click(function(){

    var elem = $(this).closest('.item');

    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    elem.slideUp();
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
            }
        }
    });
```

really I just need to get the click event to recognize the second one instead of the first, and return correctly. Right now if you click, i get the original ( browser default) and i get the second afterwards. I think the "if statement" is whats throwing me off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using both of those on the same page?

Comment: would it be more efficient in the 'original' just do 

    return confirm( '<?php _e( 'Are you sure?' ) ?>' );

???

Comment: hmm, this is the default that buddy press uses, I can definitely change it as i see fit though. @ Sam no, my attempt is to just use the second. The first is the default.

Comment: So what is your question at this point? What do you mean by "original" and "return correctly"?

Comment: well the original is the default built into buddy press, i want to exchange that with this plugin's call to a custom dialog box to carry out the confirmation instead so that i can style it. It seems like it's kinda funny though, like, when i tried the the code you posted, it doesn't work. it deletes without any confirmation. I dunno, this is where i got the plugin in : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the jQuery `click` method returns a jQuery object. It will not return whatever you specify to return in the anonymous function passed to `.click()`.

Secondly, your if statement has syntax errors. It should be written like this:

```
if ( confirm( "<?php _e( 'Are you sure?' ) ?>" ) ){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, like i commented above, This is the code provided via buddy press, but I'm doing changes and customizations. So thanks for catching that